# Integrate with non commutative symbols in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I have

```
x=Symbol('x',commutative=False)
```

and some expression

```
expr = x**2+x
```

then if you try to integrate this

```
integrate(expr,x)
```

the following error appears:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1295, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 486, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 774, in _eval_integral
    poly = f.as_poly(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 706, in as_poly
    poly = Poly(self, *gens, **args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 113, in __new__
    opt = options.build_options(gens, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 731, in build_options
    return Options(gens, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 154, in __init__
    preprocess_options(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 152, in preprocess_options
    self[option] = cls.preprocess(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 293, in preprocess
    raise GeneratorsError("non-commutative generators: %s" % str(gens))
sympy.polys.polyerrors.GeneratorsError: non-commutative generators: (x,)
```

Is there any way to fix this? Because I really need x to be non commutative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the advanced integration methods (Risch, Meijer G) need the variable to be commutative; they rely on polynomials working as they normally do. Restricting the integration methods to "manual" (elementary calculus techniques) avoids the error:

```
x = Symbol('x',commutative=False)
integrate(x**2 + x, x, manual=True)
```

returns `x**2/2 + x**3/3`. The tradeoff is that only simple integrals (on the level of calculus courses) will be evaluated.

That said, I'm not 100% sure that all integration rules in `manualintegrate` module are written with the possible lack of commutativity in mind.

Comment: This still fails sometimes, for instance, for `x*y` wrt `x` when both `x` and `y` are noncommutative.

Comment: @asmeurer Yes, the ConstantTimesRule expects the constant to be on the left. I don't know how much calculus we can really expect to work with noncommutative symbols. E.g., the commutator `x*y - y*x` is a nontrivial function of noncommutative x, but its derivative with respect to `x` is identically zero...